How to make my latex code to be continuously showing my big table in the next pages
\begin{sidewaystable*}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Summary of VEP-based BCI Studies}
\label{tab:reviewed_papers}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{% 
        \begin{tblr}{
        colspec={ccp{2cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}p{2cm}p{5cm}p{5cm}},
        row{1}={font=\bfseries, bg=gray!4},
        hlines = {}
        }
        Ref. & Year & Modality & Application & Data Set & Model & Calibration & Performance & Challenges \\
        \cite{piotr_bialas_2014} & 2014 & SSVEP & Tested the ability of a consumer-grade equipment in detecting SSVEP responses with high-frequency stimuli. & Private dataset: 15 participants (including 3 females), 40 trials/session. & \textbf{Feature Extraction:} Common Spatial Filtering for dimension reduction of signal and Canonical Correlation; \newline \textbf{Classification:} 3 logistic regression classifiers were applied. & Calibration needed. & Low Frequencies (17Hz, 19Hz, 23Hz, 25Hz) - $80\%\pm15\%$; \newline\newline Higher Frequencies (31Hz, 33Hz, 37Hz, 40Hz) - $67\%\pm12\%$; \newline\newline Evaluation for frequencies within a set of 35Hz–40Hz is $64\%\pm22\%$. & 1. The amplitude of brain responses for higher frequencies is smaller, making detection and analysis more difficult. \newline 2. Results indicate that the system does not perform uniformly across different users. \newline 3. The practical implementation still needs to balance the benefits of reduced fatigue with the technical difficulty of accurately detecting high-frequency SSVEPs. \\
        
        \cite{bhat_swati_2018} & 2018 & SSVEP & Authors compared the performance of a 3-class BCI system in controlling a game.  & Private dataset: 3 male and 2 female subjects. All subjects had normal or correct-to normal vision. & \textbf{Classifiers:} LDA, SVM, and RVM. \newline Common Spatial Filtering for dimensionality reduction. \newline \textbf{Feature Extraction:} Band Power Feature Extraction.  & Calibration free, both online and offline evaluation. & Online phase: \newline SVM (85\% linear, 90\% RBF); \newline LDA (78\%). \newline\newline Offline phase: \newline RVM (84\%).  & 1. Neural responses recorded during visual stimulation varied significantly in amplitude, affecting the accuracy and reliability of the BCI system for different individuals. \newline 2. The system is sensitive to external noise and distractions, which could have degrade its effectiveness. \\

        \cite{avinash_kumar_singh_2020} & 2020 & Five BCI paradigms: \newline 1. SSVEP; \newline 2. MI; \newline 3. Attention; \newline 4. ERN; \newline 5. RSVP. & The paper examines how using BCI video game for an extended time may influence the state of a user's resting brain. & Private dataset: 14 participants (20–26 years). \newline Gem-swapping game with a BCI paradigm, 90 min/day, 5 days/week, for 4 weeks. & Model \textcolor{red}{MVAR} & Calibration needed. & Extended engagement with BCI resulted in significant (p < 0.05) alterations in information flow and connection metrics for Coh and PDC in the fronto-central, fronto-parietal, and centro-parietal networks. & Challenges \newline \textcolor{red}{NEED TO REVIEW AGAIN!
      Using EEG electrodes to conduct Coh and PDC analysis is a restriction. Analysis may be performed on the brain component that was removed from the ICA. However, the limited duration of each participant's resting data (3 minutes) made it impossible to get sufficient components for connection analysis, except eye blinks. Thus, a study was carried out with EEG electrodes; however, to prevent false-positive findings, we also used a SIFT to cross-verify the data obtained from developed MVAR models.    Is it the difficulties with the paper?  } \\ %%%%%%%%%%%% ==== Zhenis's paper, need to check!

        \cite{elifsu_filiz_2020} & 2020 & SSVEP & BCI Gaming & Data Set & Model & Calibration needed & Performance & Challenges \newline \textcolor{red}{NEED TO REVIEW AGAIN!
}\\

        \cite{singh2020extended} & 2020 & SSVEP & The paper discusses BCI technology concerning video games. Although these studies are helpful in various fields, the main area that can benefit from this line of research is BCI for gaming. The paper examines how using the BCI video game for an extended time may influence the state of a user’s resting brain; this is because BCI has the capability of improving more than just the gaming experience, but also users’ brain operation.  & The dataset involves resting-state brain activity recordings before and after 4 weeks of game interaction. Participants played a gem-swapping game with a BCI paradigm for approximately 90 minutes a day, 5 days a week, for 4 weeks. 15 participants took part in this article, which ran for one consecutive month. Participants played the BCI-Gem game for 4 continuous weeks (5 days a week), and eyes-open and eyes-closed resting states were recorded for 3 min at the beginning and end of the 4 weeks. & \textbf{Classifiers:} LDA, SVM, and RVM. \newline Common Spatial Filtering for dimensionality reduction. \newline \textbf{Feature Extraction:} Band Power Feature Extraction.  & Calibration free, both online and offline evaluation. & Online phase: \newline SVM (85\% linear, 90\% RBF); \newline LDA (78\%). \newline\newline Offline phase: \newline RVM (84\%).  & 1. Neural responses recorded during visual stimulation varied significantly in amplitude, affecting the accuracy and reliability of the BCI system for different individuals. \newline 2. The system is sensitive to external noise and distractions, which could have degrade its effectiveness. \\
        
        Ref. & Year & Modality & Application & Data Set & Model & Calibration & Performance & Challenges \\
        \end{tblr}%
    }
\end{sidewaystable*}


Welcome to TeX.SE.

Just out of idle curiosity: Why did you set the tags biblatex and latex3?

Please tell us which document class you employ and how wide the margins are (or, equivalently, the values of \textwidth and \textheight).

As a general note: A title is not descriptive enough to know what the intent is and what help is needed.

I've removed latex3 as this seems obviously mistaken. I've left biblatex, though it is probably not relevant. I've also removed overleaf because that's just your editor and you're not asking about your editor. I've tried to guess some appropriate tags to add instead. please check and correct as needed. it would help a lot if you would add the small amount of code required to compile the snippet you've posted. if we could compile it, we might understand what you're asking, though some explanation in the question would be helpful. note that sidewaystable* can't include page breaks.

Search this site for pdflscape or rotating in combination with longtable or tblr.

@cfr - I've gone ahead and deleted the biblatex tag as well.

Later in this answer, I suggest using a combination of a landscape environment and of an xltabular environment to typeset the table across three pages.
But before I get to this solution, please permit me making the following remark: The material that makes up the table is rather heterogeneous across the five main rows -- so much so as to make its display in a table quite problematic. I think you would be much better off using five description environments -- one per cited item. This would also permit you to get rid of the switch to landscape.
E.g., the first of the five rows might be displayed as follows:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{Study of Piotr Balas, 2014}

\begin{description}[noitemsep]
\item[Ref.] \cite{piotr_bialas_2014}
\item[Year] 2014
\item[Modality] SSVEP
\item[Dataset] Private dataset: 15 participants (including 3 females), 40 trials\slash session.
\item[Model] \textbf{Feature Extraction:} Common Spatial Filtering for dimension reduction of signal and Canonical Correlation;

\textbf{Classification:} 3 logistic regression classifiers were applied.
\item[Calibration] Calibration needed.
\item[Performance] Low Frequencies (17Hz, 19Hz, 23Hz, 25Hz) -- $80\%\pm15\%$

Higher Frequencies (31Hz, 33Hz, 37Hz, 40Hz) -- $67\%\pm12\%$;

Evaluation for frequencies within a set of 35Hz--40Hz is $64\%\pm22\%$.

\item[Challenges]
\begin{enumerate}[nosep]
\item The amplitude of brain responses for higher frequencies is smaller, making detection and analysis more difficult.
\item Results indicate that the system does not perform uniformly across different users.
\item The practical implementation still needs to balance the benefits of reduced fatigue with the technical difficulty of accurately detecting high-frequency SSVEPs. 
\end{enumerate}

\end{description}
\end{document}


Finally, as promised, the solution that creates a table that spans three pages. Observe that in all three pages, the table looks unbalanced, as there are bit blocks of whitespace present on all three pages.



\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters as needed
\usepackage{iftex} \ifpdftex\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\fi
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem} % for '\newlist' and '\setlist' macros
\newlist{tabenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenum]{label=\arabic*.,nosep,wide=0pt,
   before={\stepcounter{tabenumi}%
     \RaggedRight%
     \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}},
   after ={\strut\end{minipage}}}

\usepackage{booktabs,pdflscape,xltabular,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hsize=#1\hsize\linewidth=\hsize\hspace{0pt}}X}


\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{} ll L{0.63}L{0.85}L{0.95}L{0.85}L{0.52}L{0.9}L{2.3} @{}} 
  % 0.63+0.85+0.95+0.85+0.52+0.9+2.3 = 7 = # of X-type columns

%% headers and footers

\caption{Summary of VEP-based BCI Studies}
\label{tab:reviewed_papers}\\
\toprule
Ref. & Year & Modality & Application & Dataset & Model & Calibration & Performance & Challenges \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{7}{@{}l}{Table \thetable, continued}\\
\addlinespace
\toprule
Ref. & Year & Modality & Application & Dataset & Model & Calibration & Performance & Challenges \\
\midrule
\endhead

\bottomrule
\endfoot

%% body of table

\cite{piotr_bialas_2014} & 2014 & SSVEP & 
Tested the ability of a consumer-grade equipment in detecting SSVEP responses with high-frequency stimuli. & 
Private dataset: 15 participants (including 3 females), 40 trials\slash session. & 
\textbf{Feature Extraction:} Common Spatial Filtering for dimension reduction of signal and Canonical Correlation;

\textbf{Classification:} 3 logistic regression classifiers were applied. & 
Calibration needed. & 
Low Frequencies (17Hz, 19Hz, 23Hz, 25Hz) -- $80\%\pm15\%$
\newline
Higher Frequencies (31Hz, 33Hz, 37Hz, 40Hz) -- $67\%\pm12\%$;

Evaluation for frequencies within a set of 35Hz--40Hz is $64\%\pm22\%$. & 
\begin{tabenum}
\item The amplitude of brain responses for higher frequencies is smaller, making detection and analysis more difficult.
\item Results indicate that the system does not perform uniformly across different users.
\item The practical implementation still needs to balance the benefits of reduced fatigue with the technical difficulty of accurately detecting high-frequency SSVEPs. 
\end{tabenum}
\\
\addlinespace
\cite{bhat_swati_2018} & 2018 & SSVEP & 
Authors compared the performance of a 3-class BCI system in controlling a game.  & 
Private dataset: 3 male and 2 female subjects. All subjects had normal or correct-to normal vision. & 
\textbf{Classifiers:} LDA, SVM, and RVM. \newline Common Spatial Filtering for dimensionality reduction. \newline \textbf{Feature Extraction:} Band Power Feature Extraction.  & 
Calibration free, both online and offline evaluation. & 
Online phase: \newline SVM (85\% linear, 90\% RBF); \newline LDA (78\%). 
\newline Offline phase: RVM (84\%).  & 
\begin{tabenum}
\item Neural responses recorded during visual stimulation varied significantly in amplitude, affecting the accuracy and reliability of the BCI system for different individuals. 
\item The system is sensitive to external noise and distractions, which could have degrade its effectiveness. 
\end{tabenum}
\\

\cite{avinash_kumar_singh_2020} & 2020 & 
Five BCI paradigms:
\begin{tabenum}
\item SSVEP
\item MI
\item Attention
\item ERN
\item RSVP.
\end{tabenum} & 
The paper examines how using BCI video game for an extended time may influence the state of a user's resting brain. & 
Private dataset: 14 participants (20–26 years). \newline Gem-swapping game with a BCI paradigm, 90 min\slash day, 5 days\slash week, for 4 weeks. & 
Model \textcolor{red}{MVAR} & Calibration needed. & Extended engagement with BCI resulted in significant (p < 0.05) alterations in information flow and connection metrics for Coh and PDC in the fronto-central, fronto-parietal, and centro-parietal networks. & 
Challenges \textcolor{red}{NEED TO REVIEW AGAIN!
\newline
Using EEG electrodes to conduct Coh and PDC analysis is a restriction. Analysis may be performed on the brain component that was removed from the ICA. However, the limited duration of each participant's resting data (3 minutes) made it impossible to get sufficient components for connection analysis, except eye blinks. Thus, a study was carried out with EEG electrodes; however, to prevent false-positive findings, we also used a SIFT to cross-verify the data obtained from developed MVAR models. Is it the difficulties with the paper?} \\ %%%%%%%%%%%% ==== Zhenis's paper, need to check!

\addlinespace
\cite{elifsu_filiz_2020} & 2020 & SSVEP & BCI Gaming & Dataset & Model & Calibration needed & Performance & Challenges \newline \textcolor{red}{NEED TO REVIEW AGAIN!
}\\

\cite{singh2020extended} & 2020 & SSVEP & 
The paper discusses BCI technology concerning video games. Although these studies are helpful in various fields, the main area that can benefit from this line of research is BCI for gaming. The paper examines how using the BCI video game for an extended time may influence the state of a user’s resting brain; this is because BCI has the capability of improving more than just the gaming experience, but also users’ brain operation.  & 
The dataset involves resting-state brain activity recordings before and after 4 weeks of game interaction. Participants played a gem-swapping game with a BCI paradigm for approximately 90~minutes a day, 5~days a week, for 4 weeks. 15~participants took part in this article, which ran for one consecutive month. Participants played the BCI-Gem game for 4 continuous weeks (5 days a week), and eyes-open and eyes-closed resting states were recorded for 3 min at the beginning and end of the 4~weeks. & 
\textbf{Classifiers:} LDA, SVM, and RVM. 
\newline Common Spatial Filtering for dimensionality reduction. 
\newline \textbf{Feature Extraction:} Band Power Feature Extraction.  & 
Calibration free, both online and offline evaluation. & 
Online phase: \newline SVM (85\% linear, 90\% RBF); \newline LDA (78\%).  
\newline Offline phase: RVM (84\%).  & 
\begin{tabenum}
\item Neural responses recorded during visual stimulation varied significantly in amplitude, affecting the accuracy and reliability of the BCI system for different individuals.
\item The system is sensitive to external noise and distractions, which could have degrade its effectiveness. 
\end{tabenum}
\\

\end{xltabular}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}


and the first option is less likely to run afoul of overleaf's limits (unless this is a paid account, of course).
